Who anointed David at Hebron? (2 Samuel 2)
2 Sam. 2

1 After this, David inquired of the Lord, “Shall I go up into one of
the cities of Judah?” The Lord replied to him: Go up. Then David
asked, “Where shall I go?” He replied: To Hebron... 4 Then the men of Judah came
there and anointed David king over the house of Judah.

Who would have anointed David at Hebron? Samuel was long dead, so it had to be someone else. Hebron seems to have been the capital city of Judah prior to the capture of Jerusalem, although I cannot tell if it carried any administrative authority over other towns. Does the Bible provide information as to what if any spiritual centers existed there or nearby? Should we presume that David would have been anointed by a priest known to have supported him in his troubles with Saul? One such was Abiathar (1 Samuel 30:7), whom ministered with the ephod to David and who later became a priest in Jerusalem. Are there other candidates?

Anointment in the Bible can be perceived in two categories;

Divine anointment - Such as Saul & David, anointed by Samuel; Elisha by Elijah  (1 Kings 19-21); Jehu by Elisha's representative (2 Kings 9:1-10); Hazael by Elisha (2 Kings 8:7-15). The characteristics of this anointment includes: 1) It is not restricted to Israelites, as seen in the case of Hazael, who was an Aramite. 2) It is not limited to the use of oil, as Elijah anointed Elisha with his cloak, and Elisha anointed Hazael with words. 3) It is prophetic, as all anointed individuals were destined to become kings at a later time. 4) the person performing the anointment was always divinely appointed.
Public anointment - Besides the account of David in 2 Samuel 2:4, one particular account is Jehoahaz in 2 Kings 23:30, who was anointed king by the people of Judah following the death of his father Josiah.

The characteristics of public anointment are often considered a ritual rather than a divine order, and the person conducting the ritual is often anonymous.
Therefore, the Bible does not specify who anointed David at Hebron.

2 Sam. 5:1-4 KJV

Then came all the tribes of Israel to David unto Hebron, and spake, saying, Behold, we are thy bone and thy flesh. Also in time past, when Saul was king over us, thou wast he that leddest out and broughtest in Israel: and the LORD said to thee, Thou shalt feed my people Israel, and thou shalt be a captain over Israel. So all the elders of Israel came to the king to Hebron; and king David made a league with them in Hebron before the LORD: and they anointed David king over Israel. David was thirty years old when he began to reign, and he reigned forty years.

KJV  2 Samuel 19:11

And king David sent to Zadok and to Abiathar the priests, saying, Speak unto the elders of Judah, saying, Why are ye the last to bring the king back to his house? seeing the speech of all Israel is come to the king, even to his house.

Zadok and Abiathar were two significant priests during the reign of King David and the early reign of Solomon. Both played crucial roles in Israel’s religious and political life, each with unique allegiances that positioned them differently during the transition of power from David to Solomon.
Zadok – He was a descendant of Eleazar, the son of Aaron, and served as a loyal priest to David. Zadok supported David in times of crisis, including Absalom’s rebellion, and later backed Solomon’s succession to the throne. He was rewarded by Solomon with the position of high priest (1 Kings 2:35), representing continuity in the priestly line from Eleazar. This established Zadok’s lineage as one of the most prominent in Israel, later emphasized in prophetic texts, such as in Ezekiel (Ezekiel 44:15).
Abiathar – A descendant of Eli, Abiathar belonged to the priestly line of Ithamar, another son of Aaron. He also served alongside David and was one of the few survivors of Saul’s massacre of the priests at Nob (1 Samuel 22:20-23). However, during the struggle for the throne between Adonijah and Solomon, Abiathar supported Adonijah, David’s eldest living son. This act of allegiance led to his removal from the priesthood when Solomon took the throne. Solomon dismissed him and sent him into exile at Anathoth, fulfilling the prophecy against Eli’s house (1 Kings 2:26-27).
These two priests not only represented distinct priestly lineages but also reflected the complex political and religious dynamics in Israel during the transition between David’s and Solomon’s reigns. The continuation of Zadok and the dismissal of Abiathar symbolized, in a way, the rise and fall of different priestly houses in Israel’s history.

the problem with Zadok is that he doesn't appear in the text until after David is king in Jerusalem. (2 Samuel 5). Abiathar goes back to 1 Samuel 22. So as far as the anointing at Hebron goes, I think Abiathar is a better candidate.

The silence regarding Zadok in 2 Samuel 2 may have been intentional, preserving his significance until David’s consolidation in Jerusalem. As a priest from Eleazar’s lineage, Zadok held spiritual legitimacy, and although not directly mentioned, his influence and support for David’s reign appear strategic, unlike Abiathar from Eli’s line, who ultimately lost his position. Zadok emerges as a decisive figure, especially in Jerusalem, to unify the kingdom and strengthen the continuity of the priestly line loyal to David.
